# Split string based on condition in r

Tags: r, dplyr, stringi

I'm working with a table that looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

id <- c(1, 1, 2, 2)
year <- rep(1990:1991, 2)
occ <- c("former farmer carpenter", "cleaner janitor", "carpenter", "carpenter former cleaner")
old_occ <- c("former farmer", "cleaner", "", "")

df <- tibble(id, year, occ, old_occ)
```

I would like to split the strings so that all titles are given a separate cell, like this:

```
id occ1            occ2
1  former farmer   carpenter
1  cleaner         janitor
2  carpenter
2  carpenter       former cleaner
```

Now, this would be pretty straightforward if all the cells contained either one occupation, like "carpenter", or two occupations, like "cleaner janitor". However, as you can see some occupational titles hold information about previous professions, like "former cleaner". These occupational titles consist of two strings and can come either before or after the currently held occupation in the cell.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can split the strings to achieve the result that I want?

Comment: Maybe something like: `strsplit(gsub("former ", "former_", df$occ), " ")` ?

Comment: Well, it could be possible that there are more than 2 occupations, but there are no other prefixes than 'former'.

Comment: Note, that I've enhanced my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65408302/6574038) with `sprintf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *@GKi* suggested in comments, you could use `gsub` to combine the `"former_*"` titles with an `"_"` using regular expressions. Then `strsplit` and `unique`ify, adjust the `length`s and `cbind`.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) gsub("(?<=former)\\s", "_", x, perl=TRUE))
tmp <- lapply(strsplit(Reduce(paste, df[c("occ", "old_occ")]), " "), unique)
mxlen <- max(lengths(tmp))
res <- cbind(df[-(3:4)], 
             `colnames<-`(t(sapply(tmp, `length<-`, mxlen)), 
                          paste0("title", sprintf(paste0(".%0", mxlen, "d"), seq(mxlen)))))
res
#   id year      title.01       title.02
# 1  1 1990 former_farmer      carpenter
# 2  1 1991       cleaner        janitor
# 3  2 1990     carpenter           <NA>
# 4  2 1991     carpenter former_cleaner
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new row for each word, combine `former` with next word value and get data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(occ) %>%
  group_by(id, row) %>%
  group_by(grp = lag(cumsum(occ != 'former'), default = 0) + 1, .add = TRUE)  %>%
  summarise(occ = paste0(occ, collapse = ' ')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = occ, names_prefix = 'occ') %>%
  ungroup %>% select(-row)

#     id occ1          occ2          
#  <dbl> <chr>         <chr>         
#1     1 former farmer carpenter     
#2     1 cleaner       janitor       
#3     2 carpenter     NA            
#4     2 carpenter     former cleaner
```